# Openpyxl/Pandas - Convert CSV to XLSX

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I'm trying to convert a `CSV` file to an `Excel` file but after trying most of the suggestions from the web, the closest I got is using this piece of code:

Input file looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X8VR.jpg)

```
pathcsv = r'C:\Users\Python\test.csv'
pathxls = r"C:\Users\Python\test123.xlsx"


wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        ws.append(row)

wb.save(pathxls)
```

Problem in here is that the output file looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaICw.jpg) (see highlighted)

Another try was with `pandas`.

```
data = pd.read_csv(pathcsv, sep="\t")
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_excel(pathxls, index=False)
```

But the output looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2LUI.jpg)

Does anyone got any clue on how to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: `pd.read_csv(pathcsv, sep="\t")` already returns a DataFrame, there's no need for the `df = pd.DataFrame(data)`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It's an encoding problem, play with the `encoding` value on the input and output, i.e.: `pd.read_csv(pathcsv, encoding="latin_1") ` https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings, if possible, please provide csv sample so we can test because image aren't helpful.

Comment: Why are you using `sep="\t"` if it's really a CSV file? Judging from your last screenshot, your CSV file actually uses *c*ommas to *s*eparate *v*alues.

Comment: @jjramsey, that's just trial & error.
Whenever I used comma, I got this error: 

`ParserError: Expected 3 fields in line 5, saw 59`

sep="\t" was the only option that helped me export something.

Comment: I know you found your solution, but if you get a `ParserError` like that, it means that the number of fields per row isn't consistent, which is a problem for Pandas since dataframes are rectangular data structures and *need* every row to have the same number of fields. Setting `sep="\t"` just papers over the problem. My guess is that since the CSV file had no tabs, Pandas saw only *1* field per row, with each field being a long string containing several commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on this one.

I just added  the encoding param as utf-8 and it worked fine.

`with open(pathcsv, 'r+', encoding="utf-8") as f:`

Thanks everyone for your help. It was a nice first post :)

Answer (score 0):

Further to the comment above, have you tried using different encodings? You can try using the `encoding` argument with some from here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

In theory only in the `read_csv()` method, but wouldn't hurt to try at the export.

So have something:

```
df = pd.read_csv(pathcsv, sep="\t", encoding = 'ascii') # or other encodings
df.to_excel(pathxls, index=None)
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, but I get the following error message:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 29: ordinal not in range(128)`